# Angular - how to send uploaded image in a class. Or how to change File type to Int8Array type

Tags: angular, image, upload

Im quite new in javascript and Typescript. I really need some help with this. Im using Angular 10 and Spring Boot. I've got an interface like this:

```
export interface Product {
   productId?: number;
   sku: string;
   name: string;
   description: string;
   unitPrice: number;
   productImage: Int8Array;
   active: boolean;
   unitsInStock: number;
   dateTimeCreated: Date;
   dateTimeUpdated: Date;
}
```

And im using Angular template driven form to populate some of the fields. I want to send the Image in this object in productImage: Int8Array field. Thats the plan.

The html looks like this (plus the input for other fields):

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*"
               (change)="onFileChange($event)">
```

and class:

```
image:File;
public onFileChange(event) {
    this.image = event.target.files[0];
  }
```

so how can i change image:File to productImage: Int8Array? Or maybe i should send it some other way?

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps
HTML

```
<div class="row" style="padding:0em; margin-top: 3vh;">
<ng-container>    
    <input type="file" accept=".mp4,.mkv"id="file" multiple (change)="getFileDetails($event)">    
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="uploadFiles()">Upload Video</button>    
    
</ng-container>
```

TS

```
myFiles=[]

    getFileDetails(e) {         
    //console.log (e.target.files);   
    this.myFiles=[]   
    for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {      
      this.myFiles.push(e.target.files[i]);      
    }         
  }




 uploadFiles() 
  {      
    const frmData = new FormData();    
//you can enter other form fields here  
    for (var i = 0; i < this.myFiles.length; i++) {  
      console.log(this.myFiles[i])    
      frmData.append("Upload", this.myFiles[i]);      
    }      
    
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/', frmData,{responseType: 'text',reportProgress:true,observe:'events' })
}
```

Comment: Hey it doeast do any good. e.target.files.length = 1. And in the end, in the frmData i have the same object like at the start.